# FancyBox Padding (Top and Bottom)

Tags: html, css, fancybox, padding, fancybox-2

I have added fancy box to my gallery of images, and by default there is space on the left and right of each image, but none on top and bottom. I've tried to add padding by using CSS but nothing changes. 
This is what I did:

```
#fancy {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="fancy" class="container ">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1>Church <span>Visit</span></h1>
    </div>

    <a rel="gallery" title="Takoosh Hovsepian speaking at Skyline Church with Jim Garlow & Dr. James Dobson" class="fancybox" href="images/gallery/church_visit/770 x 510_pic2.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/church_visit/thumbs/220x132_pic2.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a rel="gallery" title="Leading worship at Calvary Church Pennsylvania " class="fancybox" href="images/gallery/church_visit/770 x 510_pic3.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/church_visit/thumbs/220x132_pic3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a rel="gallery" title="Joseph Hovsepian speaking at Downey, CA Christian school" class="fancybox" href="images/gallery/church_visit/770 x 510_pic4.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/church_visit/thumbs/220x132_pic4.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a rel="gallery" title="Andre Hovsepian speaking at youth conference" class="fancybox" href="images/gallery/church_visit/770 x 510_pic6.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/church_visit/thumbs/220x132_pic6.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a rel="gallery" title="Takoosh Hovsepian speaking at Open Doors women conference in Netherlands" class="fancybox" href="images/gallery/church_visit/770 x 510_pic5.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/church_visit/thumbs/220x132_pic5.jpg" alt=""/></a>

</div>
```

I've also tried to change the padding on jquery.fancybox.css , and still nothing changes. I am not sure if I am adding padding in the wrong place, or the issue is something else.

[Here is my gallery](http://hovsepian.com/Gallery_photo_production.htm)

Comment: what does the container class look like in the CSS?

Comment: would that be in this file  jquery.fancybox.css

Comment: possibly... did you add the container class yourself? or did someone else?

Comment: no I did not add it, I've download fancybox from their website and trying to use.

Comment: remove the container class from the div and see what happens

Comment: do you mean, padding inside fancybox ? -or- padding in your thumbnails (before opening fancybox)?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't see all of that.  JFK might be right about this.

Comment: If you are trying to edit padding of your thumbnails (before opening fancybox) then there is no reason to touch the jquery.fancybox.css file (not even trying to edit fancybox style though)

Comment: padding in the thumbnail, before opening fancybox

Comment: your css declaration `#fancy{}` is only afecting the parent container but not the `<img>` tags inside of it, maybe try `#fancy img {}`

Comment: If i did it correctly #fancy img{ padding-top: 25; padding-bottom: 25px;} still nothing happened. Can I add div around the <a> tags?

Comment: I got it to work....I made a syntax error, but now it works by adding #fancy img {}. Thank you

Comment: Can you post your answer?

Comment: '#fancy img{
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
 }'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 #fancy{
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
 }
```

Comment: if you remove the container class from the div, what happens?

Comment: I got it, the container class is not part of Fancybox. it's part of the template I am using, creating a container on that page.